# MongoDB C# Driver MongoCredential object

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The documentation for the MongoDB Driver seems to differ from the actual driver pulled from NuGet.

More specifically, the documented "MongoCredentials" (plural) doesn’t exist, but only "MongoCredential" (singular). Further, MongoServer.GetDatabase doesn't seem to have a constructor that accepts MongoCredential, only MongoDatabaseSettings (alongside a string that names the databae), and I see no apparent way of giving a MongoDatabaseSettings object a MongoCredential object.

I haven't found any examples on Google with the objects I'm finding in the driver, only ones that align with the (outdated?) official documentation.

The driver that I'm using is called (in the NuGet Package Manager) "Official MongoDB C# driver."

To summarize: How does one *actually* provide credentials in the C# driver?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm also using the [Official MongoDB C# driver](http://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/) from NuGet, version 1.8.3.

Indeed, the [CSharp Driver Tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/) seems outdated.

However, the [API documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.8.3/) is correct; there's an entry there for [the MongoCredential class](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/f50eca6d-70c8-0d83-1d7e-24e1b6a9e696.htm) (singular).

You can create a credential using either [the constructor](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/8e0f3252-590d-a4c6-a78e-7f5ed8a1274e.htm) or one of the static factory methods ([CreateGssapiCredential](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/af38a724-d085-902f-c979-a6e1caa0b386.htm) or [CreateMongoCRCredential](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/f5629097-48a4-f1a0-2862-e50f472f8056.htm)).

Next, in order to use the credentials you cannot specify them in the `GetDatabase()` call, but earlier, when you [create the Server](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/5fe2913a-f1a2-6f7c-281e-971b2514940f.htm), like so:

```
var db1Credential = MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential("db1", "uid", "pwd");
var db2Credential = MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential("db2", "uid", "pwd");

var server = new MongoServer(
    new MongoServerSettings
        {
            Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017),
            Credentials = new[]
                            {
                                db1Credential,
                                db2Credential
                            }
        });
```